# Orientdb ETL update Vertex or just add edge

Tags: orientdb

I have 3  CSV files to load in an OrientDB graph.

- People
- Product
- Purchases

People.csv is like

```
person_id;name
1;francesco
2;luca
```

Product.csv is like

```
product_id;product_name
101;apple
102;banana
```

Purchases.csv is like

```
person_id;product_id;avg_price
1;101;$1.10
2;101;$1.08
1;102;$5.34
```

I load first all the people and the products with 2 different ETL jobs.
Each job loads vertices.

How can I load periodically just the edges using OrientdbETL, as people buy new products?

All the *Transformers* and particularly **EDGE** output OrientVertex, that can only be INSERTed by the **LOADER** step.
(The EDGE Transformer adds EDGE properties to the Vertex, but the actual action is an INSERT of the Vertex). Is there a way to update a Vertex using the ETL?

Rgds,

Francesco

Answer (score 1):

An ETL json with these transformers should import the "Purchase" edges from purchases.csv and update the avg_price of each purchased product.

```
"transformers": [
{ "merge": { "joinFieldName": "product_id", "lookup": "Product.id" } },
{ "vertex": {"class": "Product", "skipDuplicates": true} }, 
{ "edge": { "class": "Purchase",
            "joinFieldName": "person_id",
            "lookup": "Person.id",
            "direction": "in"
        }
    },
{ "field": { "fieldNames": ["person_id", "product_id"], "operation": "remove" } }
]
```

*class and attribute names ("Product.id", "Person", etc)  may be different based on your DB schema.*